# LTspice simulation: voltage clamp of capacitor

Tags: diodes, ltspice, simulation, zener

I have this circuit to simulate a voltage clamp of a capacitor string:

[image: LTSPICE circuit]

The zener diode has a breakdown voltage of 4.7 V.

[image: Zener diode param]

I use step param for the parallel resistor of the cap.

Here are the results of the simulation for voltage across C3 cap:

[image: Sim results Green to Grey, 1 to 100k respectively]

I understand why the voltage depends on the resistor value; I am basicly making a parallel combination of R3//R1, but why is the voltage across C3 for high resistances even lower than the breakdown voltage of the zener diode (4.7 V)?

Comment: What is the minimum current that needs to flow in the zener to get to the knee of its characteristic curve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DC equivalent of this is a 15V supply with series resistors of 0.75X connected to between the supply and the zener.

Zener diodes, particularly relatively low voltage zener diodes, do not have a particularly sharp 'knee' and will conduct significantly at lower voltages than rated at low currents- to the point that zeners of less than about 5V are often not very useful. When you get to 3.3V and 2.4V they are execrable.

As you can see from this simplified simulation, by the time you get to 75kΩ (your X = 100kΩ) the zener voltage is down to about 3.7V.

[image]

P.S.

It's a bit messy in LTspice to plot vs. a stepped parameter (you can look it up, it involves the SPICE error log) but here is a plot showing the zener voltage as a function of your X (scaled the plot by 1/0.75).

[image]

You can see that at extreme high *and* low currents the zener voltage varies significantly from the 4.7V nominal number.

Comment: You can make it less messy by using a behavioural resistor, e.g. a `table()` (given those values) as a function of `time`. Then simply plot whatever quantity with a `.tran`.